# Hacer una solicitud ajax si otra solicitud ajax fue exitosa

Tags: jquery, ajax

**¿Cómo puedo hacer para que cuando un respuesta AJAX entre dentro del success, ejecute otro método ajax?**

Actualmente me ejecuta solo el método AJAX mas externo y el AJAX mas interno no lo ejecuta, este es mi código AJAX.

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'guardarFactura',
data: {
  "factura": varFactura,
  "nombre": varNombre,
  "apellidop": varApellidop,
  "apellidom": varApellidom,
  "fechaAlm": varFechaAlm,
  "fechacel": varFechaTel,
  "emailUsuario": varEmailu
},
success: function(resultado) {
  cargando.hide();

  $('#grillaArticulo tbody tr').each(function() {

    var fac = $(this).find("td").eq(0).html();
    var cant = $(this).find("td").eq(1).html();
    var marc = $(this).find("td").eq(2).html();
    var mod = $(this).find("td").eq(3).html();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'guardarArticulo',
      data: {
        "factura": fac,
        "cantidad": cant,
        "articulo": marc + " " + mod
      },
      success: function(resultado) {
        console.log("ARTICULO: " + resultado)
      }

    });
  });

  $('#grillaSIM tbody tr').each(function() {

    var fac = $(this).find("td").eq(0).html();
    var cant = $(this).find("td").eq(1).html();
    var marc = $(this).find("td").eq(2).html();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'guardarSim',
      data: {
        "factura": fac,
        "cantidad": cant,
        "articulo": marc
      },
      success: function(resultado) {
        console.log("SIM: " + resultado)

      }

    });
  });

  alert(resultado);
  event.preventDefault();

},
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

  if (jqXHR.status === 0) {

    alert('Not connect: Verify Network.');

  } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {

    alert('Requested page not found [404].');

  } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {

    alert('Error Interno del Servidor [500].');

  } else if (textStatus === 'parsererror') {

    alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');

  } else if (textStatus === 'timeout') {

    alert('Time out error.');

  } else if (textStatus === 'abort') {

    alert('Ajax request aborted.');

  } else {

    alert('Uncaught Error: ' + jqXHR.responseText);

  }

}
});
```

Comment: ¿Lo probaste llamando una función externa? `success: nombreFuncion,`

Comment: @Shaz asi es pero no hace nada, solo ejecuta el ajax mas externo, esto lo reviso ya que inserto datos a una BD, por eso me doy cuenta que solo ejecuta la primer funcion AJAX

Comment: ya hiciste debugger en el primer success?, que te arroja hay?

Comment: Esta pregunta necesita información adicional: ¿Hay algún error en la consola de JavaScript?¿Los AJAX internos reciben algún error?¿Existen las tablas #grillaArticulo y #grillaSIM cuando se hace la llamada AJAX? Además, deberías crear un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (aunque sé que no es tan sencillo con problemas como éste, al menos algo más completo)

Comment: pon alerts por todos lados y fíjate EXACTAMENTE dónde deja de funcionar o qué camino sigue.

Comment: Ocupa la consola y el network de chrome para ver los parámetros de salida , manda alguna cap

Comment: Lo más seguro es que te esté dando un error, comprueba la consola como bien te han dicho. Eso o que $('#grillaArticulo tbody tr') es vacio.

Comment: Lo que podrías hacer si no es pasarle todo lo que quieres de una y ya en el archivo que tienes en el servidor decidir si usas todo o no

Comment: incluiría ademas el dataType de ajax...

Comment: Y por qué mejor no te armas una sola petición Ajax!? Recolectas los datos generales de la factura y la colección de artículos. Del lado del servidor te armas una transacción que te garantice atomicidad en el registro de la factura como proceso, y devuelves lo necesario para actualizar la UI.

Answer (score 1):

No debe de tener problema al llamarse dentro de el success, probablemente del lado del servidor este mandando al error de ajax, te recomiendo agregar el 'error' a la llamada interna para descartar un problema en la misma, descartando este posibilidad otro posible error sea que algo este mal en alguno de los each que manejas en el success y nunca se mande llamar tu segundo ajax solo haciendo debug podrías saberlo.

Espero poderte ayudar, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Primero crea una funcion fuera del ajax por ejemplo:

```
function con_fe() {
  console.log("Llamada exitosa")
}
```

y muy importante comenta todos los demas mensajes que tengas, y pues si se imprime traslada toda esa data a la funcion `con_fe()` y sus parametros que tengas.... Ahora si no te imprime nada pues eso hace suponer que te olvidaste de poner algo en tu peticion ajax original te sugiero usar esta forma al usar ajax.

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            async:true,
            url: 'guardarFactura',
            data: {
                "factura": varFactura,
                "nombre": varNombre,
                "apellidop": varApellidop,
                "apellidom": varApellidom,
                "fechaAlm": varFechaAlm,
                "fechacel": varFechaTel,
                "emailUsuario": varEmailu 
            },
            success: function (resultado) {
                con_fe();
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                    alert(request.responseText);
                }
        });
        
function  con_fe(){
  console.log("Funciono");
  // Pegas aqui el codigo que quieres que te corra
}
```

Me avisas que tal te fue.... saludos programador